# Docker: getcwd: cannot access parent directories

Tags: docker, sbt, coreos, sbt-native-packager, getcwd

I have a Java app, packaged to the docker container via sbt-native-packager. When testing on local machine or other server, the container starts just fine. And on one of the CoreOS machines on Azure, I'm getting:

```
shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Success
chdir: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No child processes
pwd: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
chdir: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No child processes
chdir: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No child processes
chdir: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Success
pwd: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No child processes
chdir: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No child processes

Error: Could not find or load main class play.core.server.NettyServer
```

I have tried different ways to launch it but nothing seems to work. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue since like a month. from time to time, the very same mkdir script command fails with the message:

```
shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access
parent directories: No such file or directory
```

some pipeline worked previously - still works on around 2/3 of the runs.